# Correct way to insert SVG-string into *X*HTML with animations, scripts etc

Tags: xml, dom, xhtml, namespaces, svg

I'm struggling with namespaces in my *X*HTML application. I have to download SVGs with AJAX and now I have to create the DOM for them and insert them into namespaced XHTML.

Various ways produce various results. Basically I can use whatever, even jQuery's `$(svgXmlString)`, but the problem is that typically `<script>`s inside SVG won't automatically run when added to the XHTML DOM with jQuery. I've managed to make this work, but I still have the same problem with SVG's `<animateTransform>`. These no-script animations just won't start.

So, what is the correct way to manipulate and create DOM nodes over two namespaces? The `DOMParser`? Is that a part of the standard? I need this to work on iOS WebKit (DOMParser is there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use XmlHttpRequest then you can just adopt/importNode and then insert the responseXML document into the (X)HTML document.

See e.g http://www.carto.net/papers/svg/network_requests/index.shtml.

Comment: The techinque is obviously good, but it destroys SVG animations (<animateTransform>) that I desperately need.

Comment: You can try kick-starting the animations from script after insertion, something like `yourAnimTransformElement.beginElement()` might work.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work on iOS WebKit. However, it works in Firefox 4.0 beta, so it looks like WebKit bug.